# OSX, G/AWK, Bash - "illegal statement, unterminated string" and no file output

Tags: macos, awk, gawk

I have a script that somebody from SO kindly provided to solve an issue I was having, However, I'm having some issues getting it to work on OSX.

```
gawk --version
GNU Awk 3.1.6

awk --version
awk version 20100208
```

The original source is:

```
awk -F, -vOFS=, -vc=1 '
NR == 1 {
    for (i=1; i<NF; i++) {
        if ($i != "") {
            g[c]=i;
            f[c++]=$i
        }
    }
}
NR>2 {
    for (i=1; i < c; i++) {
        print $1,$2, $g[i] > "output_"f[i]".csv
    }
}' data.csv
```

When I run the script it gives the following error:

```
awk: syntax error at source line 12
context is print $1,$2, $g[i] > >>>  "output_"f <<< [i]".csv
awk: illegal statement at source line 13
```

From the look of it the variable of [i] isn't been amended to the output file, but I don't know why.

If I change AWK to GAWK and run the original script here is the output:

```
gawk: cmd. line:11:             print $1,$2, $g[i] > "output_"f[i]".csv
gawk: cmd. line:11:                                               ^ unterminated string
```

So I edit the relevant line to fix the unterminated string

```
print $1,$2, $g[i] > "output_"f[i]".csv"
```

Then it runs through fine produces no errors, but there is no output files.

Any ideas? I spent the majority of last night and this morning pouring over this.

A sample input file:

```
,,L1,,,L2,,,L3,,,L4,,,L5,,,L6,,,L7,,,L8,,,L9,,,L10,,,L11,
Title,r/t,needed,actual,Inst,needed,actual,Inst,needed,actual,Inst,needed,actual,Inst,neede d,actual,Inst,needed,actual,Inst,needed,actual,Inst,needed,actual,Inst,needed,actual,Inst,needed,actual,Inst,needed,actual,Inst
EXAMPLEfoo,60,6,6,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,6,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
EXAMPLEbar,30,6,6,12,6,7,14,6,6,12,6,6,12,6,8,16,6,7,14,6,7.5,15,6,6,12,6,8,16,6,0,0,6,7,14
EXAMPLE1,60,3,3,3,3,5,5,3,4,4,3,3,3,3,6,6,3,4,4,3,3,3,3,4,4,3,8,8,3,0,0,3,4,4
EXAMPLE2,120,6,6,3,0,0,0,6,8,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
EXAMPLE3,60,6,6,6,6,8,8,6,6,6,6,6,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,8,8,6,6,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,10,10
EXAMPLE4,30,6,6,12,6,7,14,6,6,12,6,6,12,3,5.5,11,6,7.5,15,6,6,12,6,0,0,6,9,18,6,0,0,6,6.5,13
```

And the example out put should be

So for L1 an example out put would look like:

```
EXAMPLEfoo,60,6
EXAMPLEbar,30,6
EXAMPLE1,60,3
EXAMPLE2,120,6
EXAMPLE3,60,6
EXAMPLE4,30,6
```

And for L2:

```
EXAMPLEfoo,60,0
EXAMPLEbar,30,6
EXAMPLE1,60,3
EXAMPLE2,120,0
EXAMPLE3,60,6
EXAMPLE4,30,6
```

Comment: If you take out the redirection and the filename, do you get output on stdout?

Comment: Oops! That missing closing quote was *my* typo in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621549/creating-multiple-csv-files-from-data-within-a-csv-file/2622254#2622254). I'll fix it.

Comment: Took out both the redirect and  filename, nothing still which is odd. Also put the .csv file through dos2unix to remove any niggling newline and end of file problems, but still no output. 

Which to be honest I find really odd.

Comment: Pretty sure it's OSX specific problem, just installed Gentoo at work to test the script, works perfectly fine.

Comment: Just for the heck of it, try setting all the initialization variables in a `BEGIN` clause instead of on the command line. And put a `print "here 1"` (or "2") statement above each `for` loop for debugging purposes. And try **ghostdog74's** [version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621549/creating-multiple-csv-files-from-data-within-a-csv-file/2621712#2621712)

Comment: Fixed, new line errors screwed me over

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two problems (on OS X platform):

1. The awk command on OS X does not support the -v flag. We can fix it by using the BEGIN pattern.
2. The OS X awk does not like the way output file constructed in the print line.

Here is my solution, which seems to work both on Mac OS X Snow Leopard and Red Hat Linux 4.x:

```
awk -F, '
BEGIN { OFS=","; c=1 } # FIX problem 1
NR == 1 {
    for (i=1; i<NF; i++) {
        if ($i != "") {
            g[c]=i;
            f[c++]=$i
        }
    }
}
NR>2 {
    for (i=1; i < c; i++) {
        outfile=sprintf("output_%s.csv", f[i]) # FIX problem 2
        print $1,$2, $g[i] > outfile
    }
}' data.csv
```

Comment: According to Apple's [man page for AWK](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/awk.1.html), the `-v` option *is* supported. And the OP removed the redirection and still didn't get any output. Something *else* is going on.

Comment: Dennis: Yes, the man page (at least on Snow Leopard) stated that -v is supported, but I tried a simple

    awk -vmyvar=5 '{BEGIN print myvar}'

and it does not work, complaining "awk: invalid -v option"

Comment: I'm assuming it's just a typo here, but the `BEGIN` belongs outside the braces. Try a space between the `-v` and `myvar` to see if that makes a difference

Comment: Dennis: It was a typo. Inserting a space works: awk -v myvar=5 'BEGIN{print myvar}'. Thank you.