# Use matching value of a RegExp to name the output file

Tags: regex, unix, shell

I have this file "file.txt" which I want to split into many smaller ones. 
This a piece of it:

`0 id:2293 7:0.78235 12:0.69205 17:0.79421 21:0.77818 ..

     4 id:2293 7:0.78235 8:0.97904 12:0.69205 17:0.31709 ..

     1 id:2294 7:0.78235 8:0.90994 17:0.49058 21:0.59326 ..`

Each line of the file has an id field which looks like "id:1" for a line belonging to id 1.
For each id in the file, I like to create a file named id`id`.txt and put all lines that belong to this id in that file.
My brute force bash script solution reads as follows.

`count=1

while [ $count -lt 19945 ]
do

  cat file.txt | grep "id:$count " >> ./sets/id$count.txt

  count='expr $count + 1'

done`

Now this is very inefficient as I have do read through the file about 20.000 times.
Is there a way to do the same operation with only one pass through the file? - 
What I'm probably asking for is a way to use the value that matches for a regular expression to name the associated output file.

Comment: show how your file looks like next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat file
0 id:2293 7:0.78235 12:0.69205 17:0.79421 21:0.77818 ..
4 id:2293 7:0.78235 8:0.97904 12:0.69205 17:0.31709 ..
1 id:2294 7:0.78235 8:0.90994 17:0.49058 21:0.59326 ..

$ awk -F"[: ]" '{print $0 > "id_"$3".txt"}' file

$ more id_2293.txt
0 id:2293 7:0.78235 12:0.69205 17:0.79421 21:0.77818 ..
4 id:2293 7:0.78235 8:0.97904 12:0.69205 17:0.31709 ..

$ more id_2294.txt
1 id:2294 7:0.78235 8:0.90994 17:0.49058 21:0.59326 ..
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the file format. I just added a snippet of the file.

Answer (score 1):

You can build a solution similar to this

[Creating multiple csv files from data within a csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621549/creating-multiple-csv-files-from-data-within-a-csv-file/2622244#2622244)

Answer (score 1):

Try this AWK script:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
{
    if (match($0, /id:([0-9]+)/, a))
        print $0 >> "file" a[1] ".txt";
}
```

Comment: tried it. got:
awk: ./try.awk: line 3: syntax error at or near ,